# Looking for an example of controls (buttons, sliders, etc...) using GLKit

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, glkit

I need to add simple controls (buttons, sliders, etc...) to a [GLKView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKView_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html), which [recognize gestures](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html), and send an action to a [GLKViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKViewController_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GLKViewController).  These controls will be used to add animated, partially transparent menus & buttons to a game I am making using [GLKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKit_Collection/_index.html).

It seems like this should be relatively simple, and extremely common.  I imagine every iOS game would need to do something like this, yet I can't seem to find one example that doesn't use Cocos2D (incompatible with GLKit) or UIKit (not drawn with OpenGL).

I would be forever grateful if someone could provide me with a working example, or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The right direction in this case is really simple. You just add your GLKView, which is a subview of UIView and your buttons to the same UIView superview. Like this:

```
UIViewSuperview
  |
  |
   -GLKView
  |
   -UIButton1
  |
   -UIButton2
  |
   -UIButton3
```

Isn't this what you want?

Comment: UIButtons are not drawn in OpenGL

Comment: Also, GLKViews are typically the top-layer view in a GLKViewController, so there is no parent view.

Comment: "There's no parent view" every view has a parent, but again, that's another discussion. You don't have to use GLKViewController, make a custom controller and make its view hold both the GLKView and the controls.